# Where is my comment?

Tags: support, comment

I commented several times to one question. I did not receive any thing after my last comment. When I try to check it though my "all actions", I did not find it after I checked my "all actions" several times across several days. (I did it often and never failed.)

At the same time, my previous comments on this question also disappeared from my "all actions". Where did my comments go?

Comment: What question are you talking about?

Comment: I do not remember the question, so I always go to "all actions"

Comment: I can't find anything. I don't see any deleted comments, eg. Are you sure you were connected to the internet when you posted? Maybe there was some glitch.

Comment: I though maybe I forgot to click in button "Add Comment" at beginning. But later I found my old comments on that problem also disappeared from my "All Actions". I saw my old comments appeared under that question several days ago.

Comment: Not that it's necessarily related, but I did find yesterday that one comment of mine from the previous day had vanished (I also don't remember what question is was for). I assumed it had been removed as part of some moderator tidying, though I couldn't think of a more specific reason.

Comment: @mkt, can you identify what post your comment was on?

Comment: @gung Unfortunately not - it's slipped my mind at this point.

Answer (score 6):

I moved your comments in one question into a chat yesterday.  The system automatically leaves a comment explaining that and in that comment is a link to the chat.  You can read that comment at [Proof Verification: Joint variance of the product of a random matrix with a random vector](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/420032/proof-verification-joint-variance-of-the-product-of-a-random-matrix-with-a-rand#comment784843_420032).

This is routine when a large number of comments appear or when there seems to be an escalating back-and-forth conversation emerging.